# Delegatecall not working

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, proxy-contracts

I have deployed the following smart contract: [0x016d87b8c98e6ad0991d128CddA435FAfbC06792](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x016d87b8c98e6ad0991d128CddA435FAfbC06792#code)

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

contract Proxy {
    uint256 public count;
    address public contractLogic;

    function setAddress(address _addr) external {
        contractLogic = _addr;
    }

    function setCount(uint256 _count) external{
       (bool success, ) = 
       contractLogic.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("setCount(uint256)", _count));
    }
}
```

and the following ContractLogic: [0x4E87a50B11A84F3270eE9C35aB9308B1d8cD8228](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x4E87a50B11A84F3270eE9C35aB9308B1d8cD8228#code)

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

contract ContractLogic {
    uint256 public count;
    address public contractLogic;

    function setCount(uint256 _count) external {
        count = _count + 2;
    }
}
```

When I send a transaction to setCount, in proxy, on remix it works perfectly but on goerli it is not changing the value of count as I expect, but if I add the following line after the delegatecall

```
require(success, "fail");
```

it works so the questions is What am I missing? Why the first contract is not working?

Here you can find the second smart contract deployed which is working as expected [0xb2962efD411BECa5421864aE4D0589A7870a57AE](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xb2962efD411BECa5421864aE4D0589A7870a57AE#code)

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

contract Proxy {
    uint256 public count;
    address public contractLogic;

    function setAddress(address _addr) external {
        contractLogic = _addr;
    }

    function setCount(uint256 _count) external{
       (bool success, ) = 
       contractLogic.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("setCount(uint256)", _count));
       require(success, "fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: Following. I tried your code on remix and it worked as expected but after deploying to goerli I get same issue as you. All I can think of is there may be some compiler optimization bug happening due to your unused variable in proxy contract. Let us know if you find answer.

Comment: i have updated my question in order to add that detail, I forgot to mention that it works on remix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case in which you did not add `require(success, "fail");` it doesn’t update count because transaction runs out of gas. Try increasing the gas limit and it should work fine.

[Transaction](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x7940fa3b57813d231823baa61c6527c697b5907cfa48316a9e5510b5b5990741) which Run out of gas but etherscan still shows succeed even tho count did not update

[Transaction](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xab341fe9599b04b4f70fde9e6993cefea5c305ce455450feb6ad23b8dc8cc2a4) send with increased gas and updates count (doesn’t matter if you added require or not)

You can use https://ethtx.info/ to see the transaction Execution trace.

[this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84839/status-is-successful-but-got-internal-transaction-out-of-gas) answer might help to understand why the result of low-level operations is rejected where you did not add require after delegate call but etherscan show status succeeds even tho count was not updated.